# How to modify the active highlight in sidenav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidenav with some menu items, right now I have an active class applied to the current li, it will highlight the li with a background color (in this case: #3596d5).

Instead of highlighting the entire li, I should like just a  tiny section (about 10 pixels) to the left of the text to be highlighted, I can't think of any way to do this.

Here is the photoshopped result that I am looking for:

[image: The style I am looking for]

My current HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-primary">
    <ul class="nav nav-main">
        <li class="active">
            <a class="auto nav-item text-white" href="#">
                <span>Home</span>
            </a> 
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a class="auto nav-item" href="#">
                <span>Item 2</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a class="auto nav-item" href="#">
                <span>Item 3</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a class="auto nav-item" href="#">
                <span>Item 4</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a class="auto nav-item" href="#">
                <span>Item 4</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My current CSS:

```
.text-white {
    color: white;
}
.nav-primary ul.nav > li > a {
    padding: 15px
}
nav {
    background-color: black;
}
.active {
    background-color: #3596d5;
```

}

My jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vtp7omx2/) (This is using bootstrap external resource)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you could set a `border-left` property on the active element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ::before like this:

```
.active::before{
    content: ' ';
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #3596d5;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vtp7omx2/3/

Comment: After experimenting with the other solutions, I like this one the best, it doesn't require any adjustment of the margins! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.active {
    background-color: #000; border-left:5px solid #069;
}
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovkvxt0u/)

Comment: This worked really well, I didn't even think about that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a gradient background:

```
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0px, rgba(32, 124, 202, 1) 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 11px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtp7omx2/1/